# Not able to display list on jsp from spring session

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In my application i want to store list data on application startup, and i want to fetch it on jsp pages whenever it required. for which i have defined `bean` as below

```
<beans:bean id="systemService" class="com.mycompany.System" init-method="setMasterList" lazy-init="false"/>
```

`component` is as follows

```
@Controller
@Component("system")
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_GLOBAL_SESSION)
public class System
{
    public Map<Integer, String> masterList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public Map<Integer, String> populateMasterList()
    {
        masterList.put(1, "About US");
        masterList.put(2, "About US");
        return masterList;
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> getMasterList()
    {
        return masterList;
    }

    public void setMasterList()
    {
        this.masterList = populateMasterList();
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve this master list on jsp. i am trying to access it on jsp as follow

```
Master : ${system.masterList}
```

but on jsp it display blank. i tried with Scope as `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)` as well. but could not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<beans:bean id="systemService" class="com.mycompany.System" init-method="populateMasterList" lazy-init="false" scope="application"/>
```

And remove all annotations from System class.

```
public class System
{
   ...
}
```

In the jsp, use

```
${systemService.masterList[1]}
```

In the view resolver, add

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    ...
    ...
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What does the logs say when it loads the application context? Does it contain anything about systemService bean?

Comment: How are you acccesing the jsp? Is it through a spring controller?

Comment: yes i am accessing this jsp using spring controller

Comment: I've edited the answer. Make that change to the view resolver.

Comment: You can also add a `system.out.println` log statement in populateMasterList() method to see if it's getting invoked when spring loads the application context.